# Credential IIS to SQL Server (trusted Connection ?)

Tags: sql-server-2008, iis, configuration, iis-7, credentials

I have one physical server. On this server one VMWare running "SQL Server 2008R2", an another VMWare runnning "IIS 7" on Windows 2008R2

When I try to join the web site from the virtual machine where IIS is running or from another client on the network, I receive this error :

"401 Unauthorized : Access is denied due to invalid credentials", my user is know in the users of the database.

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify your application's pool identity? By default it doesn't use "network services".
I suppose that your connection string is set to "Integrated Security=True".

Gtz,
Stéphane.

Comment: even an simple index.html page in the directory (no database) give this error.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem at IIS level rather than SQL Server authentication issue. Is your web site running under "Integrated Windows" mode (NTLM/Kerberos)? You could try to switch to "Anonymous Authentication" instead:

1. Open IIS Manager and select the website that is causing the error (I assume it's Default Web Site).
2. Open the "Authentication" property under the "IIS".
3. Enable "Anonymous Authentication" item and disable others.